# Groovy nested closures with using 'it'

Tags: groovy

Code inside closures can refer to `it` variable.

```
8.times { println it }
```

or

```
def mywith(Closure closure) {
   closure()
}

mywith { println it }
```

With this behavior in mind you can't expect following code to print `0011`

```
2.times {
   println it 

   mywith {
      println it
   }
}
```

And instead I have to write

```
2.times { i ->
   println i 

   mywith {
      println i
   }
}
```

My question is: why closures without parameters override `it` variable even if they don't need it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think it has something to do with the [formal Closure definition](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#_defining_a_closure) of Groovy:

> Closures may have 1...N arguments,
>   which may be statically typed or
>   untyped. The first parameter is
>   available via an implicit untyped
>   argument named it if no explicit
>   arguments are named. If the caller
>   does not specify any arguments, the
>   first parameter (and, by extension,
>   it) will be null.

That means that a Groovy Closure will always have at least one argument, called *it* (if not specified otherwise) and *it* will be null if not given as a parameter.

The second example uses the scope of the enclosing closure instead.

Answer (score 25):

If you define a closure like this

```
def closure = {println "i am a closure"}
```

It appears to have no parameters, but actually it has one implicit parameter named `it`. This is confirmed by:

```
def closure = {println "i am a closure with arg $it"}
closure("foo")
```

which prints

> "i am a closure with arg foo"

If you really want to define a closure that takes 0 parameters, use this:

```
def closure = {-> println "i am a closure"}
```

Your example could therefore be rewritten as:

```
2.times {
   println it 

   mywith {->
      println it
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Explicit zero-parameters closure won't look nice in mini-dsls.

Comment: So I believe in this case the `it` variable that gets printed in the `mywith` nested closure is a [free variable](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures#Closures-Freevariables).