# How do I shadow a variable in a Groovy closure?

Tags: groovy

I've noticed that I can't shadow variables in closures. For example, in a function:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
def foo() {
    def item = 'whatever'
    x.findAll{ item -> item > 1 }
}

foo()
// org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
// /private/tmp/foo.groovy: 4: The current scope already contains a variable of the name item
//  @ line 4, column 14.
//        x.findAll{ item -> item > 1 }
//                 ^
```

This is a problem for me, because I want to define a DSL with closures, which [implicitly define `it`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2361650/509706) and surprise my users:

```
def callClosure(body) {
    body()
}

x = [1, 2, 3]
callClosure { x.findAll{ it -> it > 1 } } // same error
```

Is it possible to define closures with variables, even if they might shadow the enclosing scope?

I've tried this:

```
callClosure { x.findAll{ def it -> it > 1 } }

callClosure { x.findAll{ final it -> it > 1 } }
```

but both produce the same error.

Can I declare parameters in my closures such that I don't need to worry about them being defined in parent scopes?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `it` variable from the delegate in the closure? Closures have three sources of values - `this`, `owner` and `delegate`. Removing `it` from all three of these might be possible?

Comment: This looks like a compile time error, so messing with the delegation (at runtime) wont help (i guess)?

Comment: @christopher aha, great suggestion! `x.findAll{ it > it }` does indeed work fine. I'd love to find a solution that worked in the general case though -- this doesn't help with my `{ item -> item > 1 }` example.

Comment: Some rules can only be bent so far I'm afraid, even in Groovy where rules are really just vague guidelines. @WilfredHughes

Comment: `x.findAll{ it > it }` should of course be `x.findAll{ it > 1 }`. Argh.