# Factorize gradle task

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I would like to factorize code in my gradle script (for android project, don't know if it change something) that looks like this right now:

```
task gifFoo (dependsOn: 'test') {
    doLast{
        exec{
            commandLine 'convert', '-delay', '200', 'screenshots/jpgFoo*',
                                   '-resize', '380x',
                                   'screenshots/gifFoo.gif'
        }
    }
}

task gifBar (dependsOn: 'test') {
    doLast{
        exec{
            commandLine 'convert', '-delay', '200', 'screenshots/jpgBar*',
                                   '-resize', '380x',
                                   'screenshots/gifBar.gif'
        }
    }
}

task gif(type: Copy, dependsOn : ['gifFoo', 'gifBar']) {
    from("screenshots")
    into("doc")
    include("*.gif")
}
```

The number of `gif*` tasks will grow with the project and for know it's basically copy/pasted changing "Foo" with "Bar" which is not a good option.

I'm pretty new to gradle script and I didn't figured out a simple way to look/create a function/create a task macro, how do you do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
task gif(type: Copy) {
    from("screenshots")
    into("doc")
    include("*.gif")
}
['Foo', 'Bar'].each { thing ->
    task "gif$thing"(dependsOn: 'test') {
        doLast{
            exec{
                commandLine 'convert', '-delay', '200', "screenshots/${thing}*", 
                                   '-resize', '380x',
                                   "screenshots/gif${thing}gif" 
            }
        }
    }
    gif.dependsOn "gif$thing" 
}
```

Or perhaps

```
task gifAll {
    doLast{
        ['Foo', 'Bar'].each {thing ->
           exec{
               commandLine 'convert', '-delay', '200', "screenshots/jpg${thing}*", 
                                   '-resize', '380x',
                                   "screenshots/gif${thing}.gif" 
           } 
        }
    }
}
```

If it was me, I'd put all the gifs to convert into a single folder and convert everything rather than maintaining the list. This way as you add more gifs to the folder they are automatically converted

Eg:

```
task gifAll {
    inputs.dir 'src/main/screenshot' 
    outputs.dir "$buildDir/converted-screenshots" 
    doLast{
        fileTree('src/main/screenshot').each {thing ->
           exec{
               commandLine 'convert', '-delay', '200', thing.absolutePath, 
                                   '-resize', '380x',
                                   "$buildDir/converted-screenshots/$thing.name" 
           } 
        }
    }
} 
task gif(type: Copy, dependsOn: gifAll) {
    from("$buildDir/converted-screenshots")
    into("$buildDir/doc")
    include("*.gif")
}
```

Comment: looks like I'm having trouble using ``${it}`` inside the ``exec`` block, it looks interpreted this way ``org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecAction_Decorated@107b6869`` instead of ``Foo``?

Comment: Try `['Foo', 'Bar'].each { thing -> ...}` instead then refer to "thing" instead of "it"

Comment: Thats working... could you explain why ? And modify your answer with the "thing"  and I'll accept it. Big thanks ;)

Comment: Each closure has an implicit "it" variable, your issue was caused by another closure nested within the top level closure (which has its own "it" variable). This meant we were forced to name the variable instead of relying on the implicit "it". Answer updated. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361650/groovy-nested-closures-with-using-it